# DNS update for newly created domain name?

Tags: domain-name-system

A few hours ago I registered a new .lu domain name. I can see my whois information in whois web sites but in the section of DNS it says no DNS. My DNSs are set to a third part hosting provider in the settings. So, no one can see my web site on the internet now.

.com domain names take few seconds to be able to use. But why is that my .lu domain name has no DNS still?

Edit: The registrar is [Gandi](http://www.gandi.net/) and the domain name ends with [.lu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.lu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use dig (windows http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/)

```
dig <name of your site>
```

should return loads of information, what the authoritative name servers are, any error codes that are being returned.

also `dig <name of your site> +trace` will trace out all the dns servers involved in a recursive lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Whois is not the tool for checking DNS resolution.  Try using nslookup or host to see if your domains resolvable.

If you are using a third party DNS service, you need to enter the nameservers they assigned to you into the registrars data.  They will publish then nameservers for your domain.  Your third party DNS service will used to resolve DNS queries for your domain.

I suspect you haven't supplied the registrar with your name servers, or they are slow in publishing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Different top-level domains have different policies on how often they update their respective root servers.  For the older top-level names such as `.com` the updates happen fairly quickly.  They still generally claim a 24-48 hour window to expect changes to be published, but at this point it's near real-time.  I've seen them go through as quickly as a few minutes and take as long as 12 hours in recent months.  It also depends on the individual registrar and how often they submit updates to the registry.  I had some name server changes on a .com domain once that hadn't gone through after 24 hours and it turns out the registrar was having a problem on their systems so the change wasn't getting through to the registry.

I would recommend getting with your registrar to find out how fast they send updates to the registry, and also how quickly that particular registry usually updates their respective top-level zone information.  I've heard that some of the smaller ones can take days to push changes through.  Others will verify that the DNS server(s) listed are authoritative for the domain before they will push the update through.  It all depends on the policies in place.